# Дублет и дубликат

Tags: лексика

Слово *дубликат* нередко употребляется в значении слова *дублет* (я, например, в этом значении их не различаю). Однако словари ("Новый словарь русского языка" Ефремовой, БТС Кузнецова) говорят, что *дубликат* применимо исключительно к документу, и только МАС отмечает *дубликат* = *дублет* как устаревшее.

Пример современного употребления, расходящегося с трактовкой словарей (см. выше):

> Кое-как дотащив его до сторожевого поста, он, посветив зажигалкой, отыскал на настенном щите дубликат ключей от входной двери. [Мариам Петросян. Дом, в котором... (2009)]

Да и еще стоит вспомнить различные объявления о производстве *дубликатов* ключей.

В чем проблема такого расхождения словарей с узусом? Стоит ли, на ваш взгляд, употреблять строго *дублет*, если речь идет о тех же ключах?

Answer (score 1):

Существуют **три слова** с разным значением:

Согласно словарям, **дубликат** ―  второй экземпляр документа, **дублет** ―  второй экземпляр предмета, **дуплет** ―  термин (бильярд, охота). На практике **дублет** (второй экземпляр) используется редко и кажется устаревшим. (И документы, и предметы сейчас называют дубликатами).

По тогдашним правилам делать это было нельзя, но отец пошел в школу и попросил **дубликат** аттестата: потеряли, мол.

Договорились: приду послезавтра, **дубликат ключей** от квартиры опустился в мой карман. [Анатолий Азольский. Диверсант // «Новый Мир», 2002]

Это может быть **дублет**, но никак не простая копия. [А. В. Дружинин. Дневник (1845)]

Из словарей:

**ДУБЛЕТ**, [франц. doublet] 1. **Второй экземпляр** какой-л. вещи; один из двух одинаковых предметов (в коллекции, музейном или книжном собрании). Д. книги.  2. **Охотн.** Два одновременных выстрела из обоих стволов двуствольного охотничьего ружья. Выстрелить, стрелять дублетом.

**ДУПЛЕТ**,  [франц. doublet] 1. **В бильярдной игре**: удар шаром в другой шар, который, ударившись о борт и отскочив от него, попадает в лузу. Д. в угол. 2. **Охотн**. =Дублет (2 зн.). <Дуплетом, в зн. нареч. Играть, стрелять д.

**ДУБЛИКАТ**,  [от лат. duplicatus - удвоенный] **Второй экземпляр** какого-л.  имеющий одинаковую с подлинником юридическую силу.  Д. читательского билета.

Comment: А все-таки как, по-вашему, стоит говорить: дублет или дубликат ключей? *(В ответе, в общем-то, я не нашел решения проблемы.)*

Comment: Мне кажется, что дублет - это двойник, а дубликат - это второй экземпляр, СДЕЛАННЫЙ специально.   Дублет применяется, например,  в физике, вообще в различных ситуациях. Для ключей чаще используется слово "дубликат" (здесь вопрос непринципиальный), а в других случаях надо быть внимательным.